# Configure Prometheus to scrape from a custom URL

Tags: prometheus

Can some one help me what configuration I need to add in prometheus.yml to scrape on a URL like `https://www2.abc.abc.com/servlet/metrics/`?

I was able to get the regular node exporter scraped but we are building something with custom metrics.

My current config file looks like this:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 10s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']
  - job_name: 'node_exporter_metrics'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['mockapi:9100']
```

I need a add a new job which scrapes at `https://www2.abc.abc.com/servlet/metrics/`

So far all my metrics were on http but this one is on https.

Answer (score 21):

Add a new job that configures both a custom metrics path and scheme.

It would look something like this:

```
- job_name: new-job
  scrape_interval: 5s
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['www2.abc.abc.com:443']

  metrics_path: /servlet/metrics/
  scheme: https
```

Port 443 is the HTTPS port, `scheme: https` makes sure the HTTPS protocol is used and `metrics_path` points to your custom path with the metrics handler.

Comment: This actually solved my problem too! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Stumbled on this while setting up VictoriaMetrics; you have to find `VictoriaMetrics/lib/promscrape/scraper.go:388   static_configs: added targets: <X>` in the logs, and confirm that the number of scraped targets is correct. My target was being ignored, but no warning or indication of being removed was written.